# Update list in dictionary in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

```
list = [{'id': 1, 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2']}, {'id': 2, 'tags': ['tag5', 'tag7']}]

id = 1
tag = 'tag10'

"""
#for i element in list, if list[i]['id'] == 1, update list[i][tags].append(tag)
else:
    dic = {'id': id, 'tags': [tag]}
    list.append(dic)
"""
```

I need to check if in the list of dictionaries already exists a dictionary with id = 1, and if exists, append the tag variable to his tags list, else create a new dic and append it to the list.

the script should update list as:

```
list = [{'id': 1, 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag10']}, {'id': 2, 'tags': ['tag5', 'tag7']}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the dicts in the list. On every iteration check to see if there is a key named 'id'. If there is, grab the value of the 'tags' key of the same dict and append your tag.

```
my_list = [{'id': 1, 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2']}, {'id': 2, 'tags': ['tag5', 'tag7']}]

id = 1
tag = 'tag10'

for a_dict in my_list:
    if a_dict.get('id', 0) == id:
        a_dict['tags'].append(tag)
```

If you know that this can happen on only one of your dicts you can add a `break` on the code so that it does not loop through the rest of em.

The same behavior can be achieved with an unassigned list-comprehension one-liner:

```
[a_dict['tags'].append(tag) for a_dict in my_list if a_dict.get('id', 0) == id]
```

Comment: Why you used a_dict.get('id', 0) and not a_dict['id']?

Comment: @Hyperion Because it can be the case that one of the dicts is missing the `id` key entirely. With the `get` 0 will be returned and the check will fail without an error raised

Comment: this is considered [bad style](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/#short-ways-to-manipulate-lists). you should not use list comprehensions for their side effects. you are creating `[None] * num_dicts_with_id_of_1`. if `num_dicts_with_id_of_1` ends up being large then under the hood you are creating a large object which then has to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want

```
my_list = [{'id': 1, 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2']}, {'id': 2, 'tags': ['tag5', 'tag7']}]

target_id = 1
tag = 'tag10'

for dictionary in my_list:
     current_id = dictionary[id]
     if current_id == target_id:
          dictionary['tags'] = tag
     else:
          my_list.append({'id': target_id, tags: [tag]})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [{'id': 1, 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2']}, {'id': 2, 'tags': ['tag5', 'tag7']}]
id_ = 1
tag = 'tag10'

# iterate through the list; each item in list is a dict
for  item in lst:
    # check if reqd id_ is present in the dict
    if item['id'] == id_:
      # check if tags key is present in the dict
      # if yes append to the list
      if 'tags' in item.keys():
        item['tags'].append(tag)
    else:
      item['tags'] = tag

print lst
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @CodeMouse92 since the code is pretty straightforward, I didn't feel the need to add anything. I have added comments now.