# How to add element of a list to list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

Am trying to add element of a list to a list dictionary, I have tried all my possible best but could not get it done.

list of dict

```
fortunne_500=[{'Rank': 1,
  'Company': 'Walmart',
  'Country': 'United States',
  'Industry': 'Retail',
  'Revenue in USD': '$500 billion'},
 {'Rank': 2,
  'Company': 'State Grid',
  'Country': 'China',
  'Industry': 'Power',
  'Revenue in USD': '$349 billion'},
 {'Rank': 3,
  'Company': 'Sinopec Group',
  'Country': 'China',
  'Industry': 'Petroleum',
  'Revenue in USD': '$327 billion'}]
```

list

```
rev_per_emp = [217391.30434782608,376142.84374767606,911953.2812190612]
```

Desired output

```
[{'Rank': 1,
  'Company': 'Walmart',
  'Country': 'United States',
  'Industry': 'Retail',
  'Revenue in USD': '$500 billion',
  'rev per emp': 217391.30434782608},
 {'Rank': 2,
  'Company': 'State Grid',
  'Country': 'China',
  'Industry': 'Power',
  'Revenue in USD': '$349 billion',
  'rev per emp': 376142.84374767606},
 {'Rank': 3,
  'Company': 'Sinopec Group',
  'Country': 'China',
  'Industry': 'Petroleum',
  'Revenue in USD': '$327 billion',
  'rev per emp': 911953.2812190612}]
```

I will appreciate any help in getting this done.
Thank you

Comment: Is the order of the values in `rev_per_emp` correct? ie: does `rev_per_emp[0]` always line up with the first list value of `fortunne_500`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Update list in dictionary in a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280734/python-update-list-in-dictionary-in-a-list-of-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need :)

```
for fortunne_dict,rpe in zip(fortunne_500,rev_per_emp):
  fortunne_dict['rev per emp'] = rpe
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
for i in range(len(fortunne_500)):
  fortunne_500[i]["ref per emp"]=ref_per_emp[i]
```

Of course, you have to make sure, that both lists have the same size

Answer (score 0):

using a enumerator like this

```
    for i, item in enumerate(fortunne_500):
        item["rev per emp"] = rev_per_emp[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would make it:

```
for ix, val in enumerate(rev_per_emp):
    fortunne_500[ix].update({"rev per emp": val})

print(fortunne_500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
myit = iter(rev_per_emp)
for dict in fortunne_500:
  dict['rev_per_emp'] = next(myit)
```